# Find the two longest strings separated by dash in PHP

Tags: php, string

I want to define two new variables as the longest strings from a given string. if the string does not contain any dashes, just choose it for both.

Example:

```
$orig=`welcome-to-your-world`

$s1=`welcome`
$s2=`world`

$orig=`welcome-to-your-holiday`

$s1=`welcome` // order not important
$s2=`holiday`// order not important


$orig=`welcome`

$s1=`welcome` 
$s2=`welcome`
```

Comment: hints: see `explode` and `strlen`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with `explode` and sorting result array by length of words:

```
$orig = 'welcome-to-your-world';
$parts = explode('-', $orig);
if (1 < count($parts)) {
    usort($parts, function($a, $b) { return strlen($a) < strlen($b); });
    $s1 = array_shift($parts);
    $s2 = array_shift($parts);
} else {
    $s1 = $s2 = $orig;
}

echo $s1 . PHP_EOL . $s2;
```

Fiddle [here](https://3v4l.org/7IQEP).

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your string is in dash-case (words in lower case separated by dashes).

So, you can do the following:

```
// convert origin in an array
$origin_array = explode("-", $origin);
//retrivies the first element from array

$s1 = '';
$s2 = '';

// get the longest string
foreach($origin_array as $word) {
  if(strlen($word) > strlen($s1)) {
     $s1 = $word;
  }
}

// remove the longest word from the array
$origin_array = array_diff($origin_array, [$s1]);
// get the second longest string
foreach($origin_array as $word) {
  if(strlen($word) > strlen($s2)) {
     $s2 = $word;
  }
}
```

I think that solves your problem. Hope that helps!

Note: This method is not efficient because it runs foreach twice. The other answer is better if you care about performance.

Comment: "the longest strings" it's just a coincidence that the longest strings are first and last. What if not?

Answer (score 0):

```
$orig = 'welcome-to-your-world';
$array = explode('-', $orig);
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $array);
$s1key = array_search(max($lengths), $lengths);
$s1 = $array[$s1key];
unset ($array[$s1key], $lengths[$s1key]);
$s2key = array_search(max($lengths), $lengths);
$s2 = $array[$s2key];
```